# Is it possible to use GMSPolygon with MKMapView?

Tags: xcode, swift, google-maps, mkmapview, gmsmapview

I have a GMSPolygon created via point coordinates and I need to integrate it with my mapView. However the map is mkMapView.

Since I am using clustered pins etc I'd like to keep the work I've done on the map but now that is causing issues with other functions required.

The code is as follows (mainMapView is an mkMapView)

```
let rectangle = GMSPolygon(path: path)
rectangle.map = GMSMapView(mainMapView)
rectangle.fillColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0.3, alpha:0.5)
```

Is there any way to combine GMSPolygon with mkMapView?

Thanks.

EDIT: I should probably point out that 'path' is a GMSMutablePath if that isn't already implied.

Answer (score 1):

sure, nothing ready-made but a custom bridge can be done quickly

1. you write a class `MyPolygonOverlay`. that conforms to MKOverlay. That you can initialize with the GMSPolygon.
2. allocate it, pass it the gmspolygon and add it to the mkmapview with `addOverlay`
3. you write a class `MyPolygonOverlayRenderer`. that can draw a `MyPolygonOverlay` (or rather a GMSPolygon). your mkmapview delegate needs to provide this in `rendererForOverlay` method

note for the `MyPolygonOverlayRenderer`, you can inherit MKPathOverlayRenderer and convert the GMSPath to a CGPath maybe :)

hf and feel free to revert in case of questions

Comment: Many thank. This is a bit over my head but am working through it to check.

Comment: mapkit always splits annotations in half in a way.. the annotation or overlay to add to the view (the data only) and a corresponding view or renderer (that visually represents the data)

Comment: Upvoted for pointing me in the right direction - my actual solution outlined below. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So with thanks to Daij-Djan, I've managed to build the MKPolygon in the following way.

```
var mkPoints = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
```

Then add the points to the array.

```
let c = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(pointInCoord.latitude, pointInCoord.longitude)
mkPoints.append(c)
```

Add the MKPolygon.

```
let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &mkPoints, count: mkPoints.count)
mainMapView.addOverlay(polygon)
```

Then add the renderer.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let pr = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    pr.fillColor = UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 204/255, blue: 255, alpha:0.5)
    return pr
}
```